# Curved vs. Straight swords

Tags: warfare, weapons

Aesthetics aside, what are the pros and cons of a curved sword vs a straight one?
Both are double-edged and the same length.
Fantasy/medieval setting.

Curved example:

[image: asymmetric blade]

https://slytherinjess.deviantart.com/art/Divine-Elven-Blade-of-Larwen-564863425

Straight example:

[image]

https://www.pinterest.com/pin/417216352955613497/

Comment: Hello and welcome. This area is both too broad (many people spent years studying swords and fighting techniques, both practically and theoretically, and list of differences with explanations could easily fill a book or few) and off topic (no world building here, just request for explanation on real world).

Comment: What about the hilt design? Is that relevant?

Comment: Please, link to image source, and make sure it is  cc by-sa 3.0 compatible.

Comment: @Mołot how do i do that?

Comment: @Philipp i wasn't thinking as much the hilt as the blade itself

Comment: @pranavB23 for this can we assume that the only difference in the blades are the shape.

Comment: I'm not a fan of this question because it's purely about the real world. Or can I make any question on-topic by adding "Fantasy/medieval setting."? "Will mowing my lawn twice a week damage it long-term? Fantasy/medieval setting." Can you perhaps specify in what way the fictional part is relevant? Are they fighting special creatures? Do they have special armor? Or are you just unaware that curved swords exist in the real world and were very popular even?

Comment: Certainly better. I don't know about licensing, but at least there are references now.

Comment: @Raditz_35 if there is another site it would fit better, then I could move it but i don't think there is a sword.se

Comment: @AjnatorixZersolar yeah i think so, Also fighting style might also be a key factor  , as different swords are better suited for differentways of fighting. a curved sword is more to slash , while a straight sword is more of a stab .

Comment: @pranavB23 My thoughts were, if you had someone who had never fought before, and you could use both and were unbiased, which would you give them?

Comment: @AjnatorixZersolar There was a proposal for a weapons SE a while ago though. http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/102381/weapons

Comment: @Raditz_35 Just because a question is about the real world doesn't by itself make a subject off topic. So long as it's relevant to building a world then it can be fine (although it may have other problems). For example "what is the maximum population an island of size X, climate Y can support" is both a real world and a worldbuilding question.

Comment: @TimB I don't see any world building aspect in this question either and I've even asked to specify it in my comment. It's apparently just about which sword is better. But then you agree that my mowing lawn question would be on-topic? This is turning into a discussion that is definitely not welcome here as far as I know

Comment: As per this example curved one is used by cocky warriors https://youtu.be/LdgRSsHobJI?t=52 basically, curved for slashing, best used with horses.

Comment: Wikipedia has an entire page dedicated to the comparison of curved and straight sword. If this is not off topic it is at least "lack of research effort"

Comment: To all those answering "different styles of combat" - it would be really useful to examine the reasons *why* there were different styles of combat. People are mentioning armor type as influencing curved vs straight swords - why was armor type different in different regions/historical periods? I feel like we're not getting all the way to the root of the matter.

Comment: @Raditz_35 We can't go into a long debate in comments but you're welcome to raise this as a meta question including both the mowing lawn and straight sword examples where there can be a more in-depth discussion. To give a quick explanation though - when building a world it can be relevant to know when certain cultures and times would use straight or curved swords. In order to know that you need to know the reasons for using one over the other. i.e. If building a "mongol horde" vs a "roman legion" what sword should I give each?

Comment: As far as I know it depends on the society you build. A swipe from a Curved sword has the purpose of cutting through leather like armors by sliding as much of the edge passed. Straight swords cut with the point and were thrust into joints of armored opponents. Especially against full plate armor straight swords were often used more as clubs, going so far as grabbing the sword-edge (with armored hands) and bashing the opponent with the pommel, which was designed for that purpose.

Comment: @Demigan straight blades do not cut with the point (except for the most superficial cuts - the point of percussion is usually a quarter to a third of the way toward the hilt, depending on the particular geometry). Against heavy armor they were used for thrusting into weak spots, as big levers for toppling your opponent to the ground while grappling, or reversed into the so-called "murder stroke" wherein the quillons or pommel made it functionally a war hammer. Saying they were used like clubs implies just smacking the blade against armor .

Comment: @pluckedkiwi and if you thrust a sharp point into a weak spot, does it cut or bludgeon? And the difference between slamming someone with a club, Hammer or the pommel of a sword is...? Naming convention?

Comment: ideal sword choice is largely dependent on the armor it is going against, but this question shows zero research initiative

Answer (score 12):

The debate about whether curved or straight swords are superior is as old as warfare itself.

Cultures all throughout history have had different preferences. Generally the European cultures (Greeks, Romans, Medieval) preferred straight, while the Asian cultures (Mongols, Japanese, Saracenes...)  preferred curved.

The main difference is that curved swords are better at slashing while straight swords are better at thrusting. This is mostly relevant if you are fighting enemies who wear armor. If the enemy is wearing chainmail or plate armor, then slashing attacks are unlikely to hurt them. You then want a straight sword which allows you to do a thrusting attack which breaks through their armor.

Straight swords also give you more range for the same weight. This is useful for fighting in close formations where every cm of range counts. That's why traditional close formation armies (like the Roman legion) used straight swords.

Comment: Don't think this is always necessary on WB, but since this question is strictly about the real world, could you include references so that people that don't know anything about swords can see if you know what you are talking about and check your information and so on? I guess you get what those are for

Comment: I remember a television program (from discovery?) about the history of weapons, where they would set warriors from different ages agianst each other. One of those was a Samurai against a knight in chainmail. Samurai did nothing against the chainmail, just made a few tiny dents (wasn't tested with a person in it). I think the knight won that fight.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid Sounds like [Deadliest Warrior](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1281313/).

Comment: At least in European history, straight swords also allowed for half swording which was a very popular way to try and bypass platemail.

Answer (score 4):

As always for weapons, there are no weapon better than another, if one of them would be useless, we wouldn't have any historical exemple of it. It's just **different combat style**.

Depending on how curved the blade is, the slash damaged would not be the same: not as deep, or as big area. Another thing to keep in mind is that sometimes, weapon can keep stuck in bodies, a slightly curved blade can prevent this.

As the other answer says, straight blade are better to thrust weak point of ennemies. However, a curved blade can be harder to parry. With a sword like the [Khopesh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khopesh), you can bypass a shield.

The Dacians also win some battles against romans thanks to [Dacian falx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falx#Dacian_falx), hitting over roman shields. Romans then redesigned their helmet, and crushed the Dacians. It's a great exemple, as romans had straight short blades: there is no blade better than another, you just have to have a blade depending on the ennemy equipment.

Answer (score 3):

### The difference is because of function:

This is a pretty simple difference. They are shaped differently because they are used for different kinds of enemies and combat styles.

Curved sword are generally better at cutting. This is because they have a longer surface area of blade that generally follows the motion of your cut and is therefore in contact with your target longer. This can create a deeper cut. With curved swords you generally try to do what is called a Draw Cut. This is when you cut something and slide the entire length of the blade against the target. By doing so you can slice much deeper than just by hacking.

Curved swords generally appeared in areas or ages where the contemporary enemy was lightly or unarmored. This is because the earlier mentioned deep cutting is very effective against bare human bodies, but not so much against chainmail or plate mail. This is was this weapons selling point was and is why we see them more in the Middle East, ancient Egypt etc where and at times when the enemy would have been more lightly armored.

[image]

Straight Swords were generally designed to have some capacity for piercing. While not every straight sword was necessarily designed to pierce, and by all means straight swords can cut, historically the great increase in the use of straight swords in for example Europe was in response to a greater need for piercing ability.

Piercing weapons I believe are more effective against armored opponents. This is suggested in Half-Swording and other techniques that emphasized using the point of a blade to bypass armor. While every sword seeks to be the most optimal tool, balancing cutting and slashing often at a tradeoff, in Europe it seems that the need for thrusting overtook the need for cutting at the onset of the high Medieval ages. This is probably why straight swords became so popular around this period.

As we move into the renaissance and age of guns, when armor again became minimal you will notice that there was a return to curved blades in the form of sabres. Changes in sword design across history tended to follow the changes in what was optimum for combat in the region and period where it was used.

[image]

Blacksmiths knowing these differences and military practitioners wanting to survive, naturally picked the best designs for whatever kind of combat they were facing. This is how these different sword came to be designed, and why they were used and became popular. Purely for best function (usually at the trade-off of cut vs thrust) depending on what was needed.

Some light reading for you, why curved for cutting:
http://raynfall.com/2539/the-physics-of-the-cut/

Why straight swords overtook curved swords in Europe during the high medieval ages (armor prevalence):
http://www.thearma.org/essays/thrusting_vs_cutting.html#.WtDq0LpFy70

This is not really official, but is a good conversation on this topic:
https://www.reddit.com/r/AskHistorians/comments/1w4gbt/why_did_knights_still_use_swords_after_the/

Why some straight swords were not pointed:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gVrYt5A3VyA

Comment: Curved sword better at cutting, fine. Straight swords being generally for piercing, not so much. There are many types of straight cutting swords which are poor at piercing - say, a Falchion, and many Medieval Arming swords aren't particularly pointy.

Comment: Falchion is an axe sword(?) and is in its own special category, and I would even argue is actually a curved sword so lets overlook that one. As for your other point, yes no not all straight sword are exclusively for piercing, but they all retain the ability to pierce. You may or may not know that there are also straight swords that are exclusively for piercing and don't cut at all like the Small Sword. One hallmark of straight swords is that they can pierce. Maybe I was unclear, but I just wanted to communicated that straight swords generally retain piercing ability.

Comment: Also see, I said (some) piercing.

Comment: There are straight swords without points. See https://www.hampel-auctions.com/img/auktionen/A108/b/Hampel-108075014.jpg  It's not going to pierce anything.

Comment: @SlowDog I'm not sure what you think of as an arming sword, but I would certainly consider them pointy. The important consideration is context - you can cut with or stab with just about any sword, but there is always the trade-off with every design consideration (estocs and smallswords being the extreme of trading cutting ability for better stabbing by having no cutting edge at all). A flexible blade or one whose point is not in line will not give a good transfer of energy as a straight stiff blade is best for punching through instead of the force being directed away.

Comment: Some arming swords are pointy, and good at thrusting. Some aren't. I've no argument that a sword good for thrusting is likely better to be straight, but the reverse - that a straight sword is good at thrusting - is simply not true.

Comment: @pluckedwiki Here's a straight, unpointed arming sword: http://sword-site.com/thread/1098/oakeshott-type-medieval-european-sword

Comment: @SlowDog. I am not really sure what you are hung up on. You seem to think that somewhere it has been stated that a straight sword must ALWAYS be a thrusting weapon. As if someone has claimed it is an absolute law of nature. Of course this is not true. You can take anything and repurpose it, alter it, have variations. This was a discussion of sword making trends and why they existed, and what needs/pressures shaped favoring straight or curved in general. In this I am 100% sure history backs up my basic summary.

Comment: Anyway, if there is something in the question you disagree with then suggest a change or modification. The answer was not particularly well received so clearly it can use some improvement.

Comment: I'm not hung up on anything. I'm trying to encourage a better answer. Your answer says "Straight Swords generally designed for (some) piercing", which isn't the case. Now, you might mean "Some straight Swords are designed for piercing", which is correct (and better grammatically), but begs the question of why there are many swords that are straight but not designed for piercing. Who used them, and why?

Comment: Everything I read seems to indicated that the point of straight swords is indeed for poking things. There were of course variations and not every straight sword poked. But the proliferation of straight swords in Europe was specifically for poking through armor. Before this proliferation Europe had curved and straight swords, and not so many straight swords as we see in the high medieval ages. So I would describe staight swords not for poking as variants? http://www.thearma.org/essays/thrusting_vs_cutting.html#.WtDq0LpFy70

Comment: I adjusted the answer to address your concern.

Comment: @SlowDog That some early examples were not needle-points in no way indicates that all arming swords had blunted tips (quite the opposite is true). More often the metallurgy just wasn't there yet and thin narrow points would break too easily, as well as less emphasis on thrusts. Your first link showing a lack of any point - pay attention to the blade geometry and relation to the hilt - that looks like a longsword which has *broken*. And did you mean to say you think straight swords could not be good at cutting (instead of thrusting)? quite wrong either way.

Comment: @pluckedkiwi You said you "consider [arming swords] pointy". Some arming swords are indeed pointy. Some arming swords are not, and never were.